# dataLayer information not showing in GTM debugger

Tags: google-tag-manager

I’m trying to implement Google Tag Manager dataLayer with the help of a developer. The devs are saying that everything is implemented the way it should be, but I can’t see the dataLayer information within the GTM debugger. I want to set Enhanced eCommerce GA and I have sent the documentation over, but it is still not working for some reason.

Here is the code that I can see once I check the page source. It's on the product page:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-M8VNL5N');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>

            dataLayer.push({
          'event': ‘ProductView'
          'ecommerce': {
            'detail': {
              'actionField': {},
              'products': [{
                'name': ‘Product Name’,
                'id': '58141',
                'price': '545.00',
                'brand': ‘Product Brand’,
                'category': ‘Product Category’,
               }]
             }
           }
        });
    </script>
```

Can you guys see something that it’s not supposed to be like that? I’m not good with JS yet and I can’t find where the issue is coming from.

I would greatly appreciate your help!

Best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, there were weird quotes and missing commas.

```
dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'ProductView', //comman was missing here and weird quote
      'ecommerce': {
        'detail': {
          'actionField': {},
          'products': [{
            'name': 'Product Name', //weird quote here
            'id': '58141',
            'price': '545.00',
            'brand': 'Product Brand', //weird quote
            'category': 'Product Category', //weird quote
           }]
         }
       }
    });
```

Result:

[image]